# Where can I get an ocean shaded relief for Central America?

Tags: raster

Does anyone know where I can get an ocean shaded relief for the Central American coast?

Answer (score 2):

[Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/features/) provides Ocean Bottom and Bathymetry rasters. Or you can go directly to [CleanTopo2](http://www.shadedrelief.com/cleantopo2/index.html) which is what the Natural Earth rasters are based on.

Answer (score 1):

Also check out [GEBCO](http://www.gebco.net/), they distribute [gridded bathymetric data](http://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gridded_bathymetry_data/)